# Mars Eclipse is sticking to a non-existing version of Java. How can I change it?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

For reasons related to the project I'm working on, I need to use Mars Eclipse and Java 1.7.
I've tried **everything** I can think of to set Eclipse to use this version of Java, but Eclipse will just point to a different JDK.
I tried overwriting the configuration via *eclipse.ini*. I've tried deleting all versions of Java I had and reinstalling only the JDK I wanted. I tried opening Eclipse from a terminal, while also trying to overwrite the settings from there.
As of now, I deleted every folder from all versions of Eclipse and Java and the relevant environment variables, and started from scratch (again). I have my JDK folder in *C:*, my `%JAVA_HOME%` is pointing towards *C:/jdk1.7/bin* and *eclipse.ini* has `-vm¶C:\jdk1.7\bin` (I already made sure I was using the right newline character and tried with both, single and double dashes before `vm` and `\` and `/` for the route to the JDK bin folder). And when I try to open Eclipse, it crashes, as it's looking for `C:\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg` (*jre7* doesn't exist). When I click OK to that window, I get another one saying

```
Java was started but returned exit code=1
C:\Windows\**system32**\javaw.exe
-jar
C:\Users\myuser\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v2015
0511-1540.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher C:\Users\myuser\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse-mars
--launcher.library
C:\Users\myuser\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300v20150602-1417\eclipse_1611.dll
-startup
C:\Users\myuser\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v2015
0511-1540.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 13a0_f0
-vm C:\Windows\**system32**\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-jar
C:\Users\myuser\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v2015
0511-1540.jar
```

Note it references *system32*, a folder in which Java has never been installed or located in, and which has never been set by me in any Eclipse setting.
I've got a week trying to figure out how to fix this and I am the only one among my coworkers who has this problem. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Doesn't -vm need the full path including jawaw.exe ?

Comment: What JDK to you have installed under Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs? That's the one you need to set. You can run Eclipse under a later version of Java (in the eclipse.ini file) and run your project under JDK 7.

Comment: @DavidConrad, I don't know. I can't get there because Eclipse clashes while I try to open it. I can't run Eclipse with any other version of Java via eclipse.ini, it doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't recognize any other version of Java because you uninstalled them all? The config from near the top of mine is: `-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin` Note: There is a newline after `-vm`; the formatting here on SO doesn't make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are two entirely different concepts of 'which JDK is eclipse using':

- Eclipse it itself an application written in java. Which JVM (`java.exe`) is it running on?
- When you develop java code in eclipse, eclipse needs a JVM for various purposes: To know that `java.lang.String` exists, for example. Or to run or debug this project. Eclipse can be configured with as many java installations as you want, and any given project can be told to use any VM you told eclipse about. **The VM that runs eclipse does not have to be the same VM that is used for running / debugging java projects you're writing in eclipse, nor to serve as bootclasspath for these projects.**

I'm having a hard time fathoming why you would have to run *eclipse itself* on a 1.7 VM. So don't; go to preferences, search for 'installed JREs', and add the 1.7 JRE. Then right click on a project, `build path`, and you can tell eclipse to use that JRE/JDK to run that project and to serve as bootclasspath for it.

The only real reason you'd have to run eclipse on 1.7 is if you are forced to use some outdated eclipse plugin that somehow doesn't run properly on 1.8+ - unlikely.

In that case, the -vm parameter is NOT the thing to use to point at the executable.

The proper argument is something like `C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.025` - I'm not quite sure how the dir structure works out on windows installations, but it's supposed to be the directory within which you find 'java.exe', pretty much. And not the java.exe that points at the real java (i.e. the one in C:\Windows\System32 is not useful for this exercise). You also don't include the 'javaw.exe' in this.